# Visio Data Source 256 characters limit

Tags: excel, datasource, visio

I'm new to using Microsoft Visio and have encountered an issue while creating a diagram using Excel as a data source. In my Excel sheet, I have columns for Symbolic Name, Name, Next Step ID, Connector Label, Admin Type, and Attributes. The Symbolic Name column serves as a unique identifier, and the Next Step ID column is crucial for linking shapes.

My configuration works well when the Next Step ID values are under 256 characters in length. However, if a value exceeds this limit, Visio truncates the text beyond the 256th character. For example, if my Next Step ID value is "type_1,type_2.... type_98,type_99" and "type_" is at the 256th index, Visio only considers "type_" and attempts to find this ID in the Symbolic Name column for linking.

I'm seeking a solution to overcome this 256-character limit as my structures can be larger. Is it possible to configure Visio to handle longer strings in this context.

Below are my excel sheet and visio diagram attachments, you may need to update the source path for visio as it will be relative to my local machine path.

https://shorturl.at/LMO24

I have tried checking documentation and other articles but did not find any solution.

Comment: NB: your link does not work (it points to a file that is not publicily shared). As for the question, looks like some sort of Visio limitation.

Comment: can you try opening link now?

Comment: Yes, now the link works. Can't help with the problem though (other than suggest to make text shorter)